# iTunes Connect: Option to change primary language is not editable

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a published app version with a list of localized languages (Danish, English-UK, French, etc) and "Danish" as primary language inside iTunes Connect.

I want to create another version but now with "English-UK" as the default language. But iTunes Connect is not showing me any dropdown for changing the primary language.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm. "create another version" means, are you creating a new app altogether or just creating new version of existing app?

Comment: I am just creating a new version of existing app.

Comment: Did you uploaded the new build for your new version?

Answer (score 0):

First, please ensure you have a new build for your new version.

Next, ensure your newly uploaded build for the new version has all languages support in `Appstore connect` like shown in below snapshot. This can be seen in `Activity -> All Builds` section under that newly uploaded build.

[image]

Comment: Localizations section only contains "English" in my case.

Comment: That’s the reason you are not getting drop down for choosing other languages. Your new build doesn’t have localization support. Please check that first.

Comment: I managed to add 1 more language (Danish) and now my build shows 2 languages inside localizations section (Danish, English). But still no dropdown available.

Comment: Did you link the newly uploaded build with localization support to the new version created in Appstore connect?

Comment: Yes, i have added the new build to new version inside iTunes Connect.

Comment: Did you able to solve this? I don’t find any other anomaly here. It should work now. Just logout and login and check.

Comment: No, still waiting for some help.

Comment: @shahxeb, any updates on this? Is your issue resolved?